# Are losses inside a stocks and shares isa tax refundable in anyway?

Tags: taxes, stocks, united-kingdom, shares, isa

I invested 40k in stocks and shares isa. They lost value by 15k.

Is there any way to make this tax deductible somehow?

I hear rich people do stuff like this often.

I'm still holding onto the shares hoping they rebound.

And i don't want to talk to tax accountants if it isn't.

Comment: `And i don't want to talk to tax accountants if it isn't.` - well... Rich people do talk to tax accountants, and not just to anonymous trolls on the Internet.

Answer (score 2):

No, they are not. See eg [here](https://www.moneyhelper.org.uk/en/savings/investing/stocks-and-shares-isas):

> Any losses made on your investments in your stocks and shares ISAs can’t be used to offset capital gains on your other investments.

Answer (score 0):

Your wording is confusing. I think you mean deductible, not refundable.

The answer in short is no.
You can only deduct losses from income.
If you lose money on an investment that is a risk you take. If the government paid you back for any bad investment they would go (more) broken pretty fast and there would be no downside for investing in risky stocks.

This is a tax sheltered account, so it doesn't matter anyway. You aren't paying tax on the gains, so you can't deduct the losses.

Comment: Are you sure about that? Not familiar enough with UK laws, but it stands to reason that if you're taxed on capital gains, you should be allowed to deduct capital losses (outside tax sheltered accounts, of course)

Comment: @littleadv The point of ISAs is that they are tax free.  There is no capital gains tax on them, or income tax if you take the dividends.  But there is a yearly limit on how much you can invest.

Comment: @SimonB yeah, that's the third paragraph of the answer, I'm asking about the second paragraph